# Group by bit column

Tags: sql-server, query, subquery

I want Group by rows with active column like result

I tray with this code and I Do not get result

```html
    WITH CTE as (
  SELECT
    RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id),
    *
  FROM test
)
SELECT

 convert(nvarchar(50),[Current Row].datetime,120) + ' To ' +  convert(nvarchar(50),[Next Row].datetime,120)

FROM CTE [Current Row]
LEFT JOIN CTE [Previous Row] ON
  [Previous Row].RN = [Current Row].RN - 1
 and (ISNULL( [Previous Row].active,0)=0) and [Current Row].active=1
RIGHT JOIN CTE [Next Row] ON
  [Next Row].RN = [Current Row].RN + 1 
and [Current Row].active=1 and isnull([Next Row].active,0)=0
```

| id | date | active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-08-08 12:05:17.817 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-08-08 12:05:20.817 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-08-08 12:05:23.817 | 1 |
| 4 | 2021-08-08 12:05:26.817 | 1 |
| 5 | 2021-08-08 12:05:29.817 | 1 |
| 6 | 2021-08-08 12:05:32.817 | 1 |
| 7 | 2021-08-08 12:05:35.817 | 1 |
| 8 | 2021-08-08 12:05:38.817 | 1 |
| 9 | 2021-08-08 12:05:41.817 | 0 |
| 10 | 2021-08-08 12:05:44.817 | 0 |
| 11 | 2021-08-08 12:05:47.817 | 1 |
| 12 | 2021-08-08 12:05:50.817 | 1 |
| 13 | 2021-08-08 12:05:53.817 | 0 |
| 14 | 2021-08-08 12:05:56.817 | 0 |
| 15 | 2021-08-08 12:05:59.817 | 1 |
| 16 | 2021-08-08 12:06:02.817 | 0 |
| 17 | 2021-08-08 12:06:05.817 | 1 |
| 18 | 2021-08-08 12:06:08.817 | 1 |
| 19 | 2021-08-08 12:06:11.817 | 1 |
| 20 | 2021-08-08 12:06:14.817 | 0 |
| 21 | 2021-08-08 12:06:17.817 | 1 |
| 22 | 2021-08-08 12:06:20.817 | 1 |

and get rusult like this

| date | duration | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-08 12:05:17.817 To 2021-08-08 12:05:38.817 | 00:00:24 | 8 |
| 2021-08-08 12:05:47.817 To 2021-08-08 12:05:50.817 | 00:00:06 | 2 |
| 2021-08-08 12:05:56.817 To 2021-08-08 12:05:59.817 | 00:00:03 | 1 |
| 2021-08-08 12:06:05.817 To 2021-08-08 12:06:11.817 | 00:00:09 | 3 |
| 2021-08-08 12:06:17.817 To 2021-08-08 12:06:20.817 | 00:00:06 | 2 |

i want group by with active and date like top result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "gaps and islands" task.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY active ORDER BY date) [Group]
    FROM test
)
SELECT MIN(date) [From],
       MAX(date) [Till],
       COUNT(*) [Count]
FROM cte
WHERE active = 1
GROUP BY [Group]
ORDER BY [From]
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4e2903e4edb753676a77db5d48ec0f4a) (with some explanations).